# Source a script with a different shell type

Tags: shell

Let's say a script is called with /bin/sh. Is it possible to source another script from that script and to have it be interpreted with #!/bin/bash?

It would appear that the #!/bin/bash doesn't do anything...

And by source, at this point I am meaning the functionality of manipulating the parent environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The whole point of sourcing a script is that the script is interpreted by the shell doing the sourcing.  If, as is often the case, `/bin/sh` is `bash`, then you will get the desired behavior.  Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [source](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command) command, or [dot](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) operator. You might also try the [env](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) command. Note, make sure you export if you're using source (or dot).